# write server to handle post request from Swift app

Tags: python, post, server

I have a Swift app that loads a timestamp and a number as a json file and sends it as with POST through Alamofire.

```
var newPostStamp = ["title": "\(stamp)", "body": string1]
Alamofire.request(.POST, "mywebsite.com/post", parameters: newPostStamp, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error)}...
```

Can you tell me how I can handle the arguments in from the POST request in my server? I am using this tutorial (http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=1658) but I don't know how to change the do_POST() method to handle my request. I just need it to show me a new page with all the timestamp:values that I have sent so far.

Thanks!

Comment: you must write an API, where you can handle your POST requests from Alamofire and manage them

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
 // Add this to your class
 import SystemConfiguration
 import CoreData


 func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

       var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
       zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
       zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

       let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress){
    SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0)).takeRetainedValue()
       }

       var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = 0
       if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability, &flags) == 0 {
    return false
         }

         let isReachable = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
         let needsConnection = (flags & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0

         return (isReachable && !needsConnection) ? true : false
  }



  func connectionService(jsonString:NSDictionary) -> NSDictionary
  {

      var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://example.com")!)
      var response: NSURLResponse?
      var error: NSError?

      request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonString, options: nil, error: &error)
      request.timeoutInterval = 100
      request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
      request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
      request.setValue("gzip", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-encoding")


    //Reconnnection 5 times
    for (var i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    {

         let date1 = NSDate();
         var formatter = NSDateFormatter();
         formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
         let defaultTimeZoneStr1 = formatter.stringFromDate(date1);

         var error: NSError?
         println("Connecting to server : \(defaultTimeZoneStr1)")

        if isConnectedToNetwork (){


               let urlData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)


               if error != nil || urlData!.length == 0
               {
                    println("Error happend timeout======\(error?.code)!")

                    continue
               }
               else
               {
                   let date = NSDate();
                   var formatter = NSDateFormatter();
                   formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
                   let defaultTimeZoneStr = formatter.stringFromDate(date);

                    println("Response from server : \(defaultTimeZoneStr)")

                    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
                    {
                          println("Status Code for successful------------------------------------>\(httpResponse.statusCode)")

                          if (httpResponse.statusCode == 502)
                          {
                              // Server is down
                              break
                          }
                          else
                          {

                               println(NSString(data: urlData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
                               var er: NSError?

                               let JSONresdata: AnyObject = (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: .MutableContainers,error: &er)!)
                              println("JSON response : \(JSONresdata)")
                              JSONdata = JSONresdata as! NSDictionary


                          }
                       }

                    }
             }
             else
             {
                   println("------------------------------------------------No network----------------------------------------------")

                   // You can add your code
                    break
            }
        }
        return JSONdata as! NSDictionary;

    }
```

Hope this might be helpful.